# How to connect to bluetooth thermal printer in Odoo

Tags: printing, bluetooth, odoo-10

I just configured Odoo application (POS) for a client! And he intends to use it in a tablet! The issue I am facing is that how could we connect odoo pos to a Bluetooth thermal printer! I heard of POSBox, but how can we achieve this without POSBox! I searched everywhere and no satisfactory solution has been found!! Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I think without POSBOX this couldn't happen. Because in odoo POS configuration if your printer is connected to only your system then no anything needed but if you are using remote printer then you must need a  cloud device which contain odoo so that your POS can able to run through cloud and remote printer can easily able to print via IP of that cloud. In this case this is only done by POSBOX.